# SELECT COUNT case

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to track data like this :

table MESSAGES
msg_id | messages | date_messages

Example data like this :

msg_id = 1
messages = really want you #LOVE

date_messages = 17-OCT-2012

```
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(MESSAGES) FROM MESSAGES WHERE MESSAGES='#LOVE'";
```

I want count messages if contains #LOVE.

Any idea ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  If an answer helped you, you should say thanks by selecting it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQL = "SELECT COUNT(messages) FROM MESSAGES WHERE messages LIKE '%#LOVE%';`

Answer (score 3):

You can use mysql's wildcard syntax:  `%`.  Check out the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html).

```
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(messages) FROM MESSAGES WHERE messages LIKE '%#LOVE%'";
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your query as

```
SQL = "SELECT COUNT(MESSAGES) FROM MESSAGES WHERE MESSAGES like '%#LOVE%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to select records where '#LOVE' is a sub-string of the the MESSAGES field I think you need the `LIKE` operator:

```
SELECT COUNT(MESSAGES) FROM MESSAGES WHERE MESSAGES like '%#LOVE%'
```

Or you could use the INSTR function:

```
SELECT COUNT(MESSAGES) FROM MESSAGES WHERE 0 != INSTR(MESSAGES, '#LOVE')
```